# Records loaded, not showing in template

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to display a list of records retrieved from an API. I can see through the Ember Chrome extension, that all the records load correctly, but somehow, the 'else' block of the #each expression is activated, and thus, no records is displayed

route

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('characters', function() {
        this.route('new');
        this.route('show', { path: ':character_id' });
    })
})
App.CharactersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('character');
    }
});
```

characters.index template:

```
<h2>Characters</h2>

{{#link-to 'characters.new'}}New{{/link-to}}


<ul>
    {{#each characters}}
        <li>Name: {{name}}</li>
        <li>Race: {{race}}</li>
    {{else}}
    No characters found.
    {{/each}} 
</ul>
```

Comment: Instead of `{{each characters}}`, try `{{each model}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{{each characters}}`, try `{{each model}}`.

The controller has no property called `characters`. It has a property called `model` (or `content`) which contains, well, the model or the content (in this case, an array of individual model instances).